# EntityFramework Migrations - Seeding per Build Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework 5 with Code First Migrations.  What I want to be able to do is specify different Seed data depending on the Build Configuration.  For example:

```
protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
{
    // This will be run in every Build configuration
    context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(new Table1 { Field1 = "Foo", Field2 = "Bar" });

    #if DEBUG
    // This will only be executed if we are Debuging
    context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(new Table1 { Field1 = "Blah", Field2 = "De Blah" });
    context.Table2.AddOrUpdate(new Table2 { Field1 = "Development Only" });
}
```

I know the code is probably wrong, I can figure out the correct method call once I know the best route to take for doing this.

Does EF have any built in method I have missed for doing this kind of thing?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The code I used in the end was:

```
protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
{
    // This will be run in every Build configuration
    context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(t = t.Field1, new Table1 { Field1 = "Foo", Field2 = "Bar" });

    #if DEBUG
        // This will only be executed if we are Debuging
        context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(t = t.Field2, new Table1 { Field1 = "Blah", Field2 = "De Blah" });
        context.Table2.AddOrUpdate(t = t.Field1, new Table2 { Field1 = "Development Only" });
    #endif
}
```

It was as Yannick said, but in the AddOrUpdate method, you need to pass in the field that EF will use to establish if it is a new entry.  Not part of my question, but thought I should provide the correct method for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already have the correct code (except the `#endif` statement).

This will work as you expect it:

```
protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
{
    // This will be executed in every Build configuration
    context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(new Table1 { Field1 = "Foo", Field2 = "Bar" });

    #if DEBUG
        // This will only be executed if DEBUG is defined, hence when you are debugging
        context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(new Table1 { Field1 = "Blah", Field2 = "De Blah" });
        context.Table2.AddOrUpdate(new Table2 { Field1 = "Development Only" });
    #endif
}
```